# Can games/DLC be completely removed from Steam, such that they cannot be redownloaded?

Tags: steam

When a game is removed from Steam, if you have it he game in your library, you can still download and play it.

But can they do something that prevents you from ever being able to download it? Like can they remove the game from their servers?

Comment: I don't know about Steam, but this has happened on consoles. In 2015, [Konami removed P.T. from the PSN store](http://www.polygon.com/2015/5/5/8557807/pt-silent-hills-demo-pulled) after the game was cancelled.

Answer (score 6):

Steam can remove games from their servers in such a way that they're also removed from libraries. For example, Steam has deleted multiplayer games where the servers have gone down permanently. The multiplayer game Order of War has been removed from user libraries on the request of Square Enix after SE took down the servers.

Steam has also in individual cases removed games from user libraries when the payment for those users has been reverted. This sometimes happens with games where the user has bought the game from a 3rd party source, but then the payment for that 3rd party source bounces (which can even happen if the payment that 3rd party source used to acquire the game is charged back, like with stolen credit cards).

Comment: Having said that, there are many games Steam no longer sells that are still in peoples libraries.  The publisher has to explicitly request that games be removed to remove them from users libraries.

Comment: I do have a game that has been removed from store page called "Warhammer Online: Age of Reckoning". But it is still available to download in my library despite being not running server anymore.

Comment: @Vyndicu The publisher (EA/Mythic) should have requested its removal since they shut down the game after losing the Warhammer license and being forced to shut down the servers.  However, since they didn't, it's still in your library.

Comment: I am just saying they will not always do it. So I just put it under hidden library as to not cluster up my other still functional games.